# Bulk create Google Maps Embedded code from addresses

Tags: google-maps

I am manually using Google Maps to create a Map, via an address, to get the embedded code to place on my Website. Is there a mechanism to bulk load addresses and get the embedded code out? I have thousands of addresses to convert to maps.

An example Address is:
428 E 4th St Charlotte, NC 28202

The embedded code from Google Maps (Enter address an using left tool menu, select share or embed map) looks like this:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3259.3378065507304!2d-80.84061599999997!3d35.22296!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x8856a02661c6b995%3A0xe460e1d558cda162!2s428+E+4th+St%2C+Charlotte%2C+NC+28202!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1440885560942" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start)

You can pass in your address as one of the [parameters of the URL](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#forming_the_url).

Example (address is URL encoded):

```
<iframe width="100%" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=428%20E%204th%20St%20Charlotte%2C%20NC%2028202&key=<your KEY>" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/example_embedded_map_address_20150829.html)